# msvc trying to compile cv::Matx<float,3,1> as a 4-element vector

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

Using MSVC 2017, OpenCV 3.4.  
Code

```
typedef Vec3f localcolor;
inline double lensqd(const localcolor & c) {
    return c.ddot(c);
}
```

Get

> error C2338: Matx should have at least 4 elements. channels >= 4
>
> note: while compiling class template member function 'cv::Matx<float,3,1>::Matx(_Tp,_Tp,_Tp,_Tp)'
>
> when compiling the ddot function.

The compiler is trying to instantiate a 3-element vector with 4 initializers.  I can't see anything in the OCV source code that would make this happen.
So do I file a bug report with MS?

And how do you suggest I get a working build?  The code is this way because I sometimes want

`typedef Vec4f localcolor;`
which BTW compiles without error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the ddot function ?

I recently had the same error by attempting to initialize a Vec3f with 4 elements.

Comment: ddot is defined for Point3 in opencv types.hpp: 
template<typename _Tp> inline
double Point3_<_Tp>::ddot(const Point3_& pt) const
{
    return (double)x*pt.x + (double)y*pt.y + (double)z*pt.z;
}
I believe Point and Vec are both derived from Matx.
The problem as you say is giving 4 initializers for a 3 element Matx.  However I didn't do that, the compiler did.   Just wondering why.

Comment: Okay, I checked the OCV source code and I can't see anything suspicious either.
Are you sure you're not using a Point4 or Vec4 at a certain moment ? I guess you might have a fourth alpha channel hiding somewhere (since you're manipulating colors)...